# Creating a column by using co-occurrence of each instance

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-manipulation, adjacency-matrix

| TRANSACTION_NUMBER | UPC_CODE | PURCHASED_UNIT | COPURCHASED_FREQUENCY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T123456 | 1040-1204-8612 | 2 | 2 |
| T123456 | 4020-4104-2120 | 1 | 0 |
| T123456 | 1040-1204-8612 | 3 | 2 |
| T123456 | 2994-8182-9311 | 5 | 0 |
| T191201 | 9879-8712-3456 | 2 | 2 |
| T191201 | 2387-1928-1247 | 1 | 0 |
| T191201 | 7417-2741-4245 | 4 | 0 |
| T191201 | 9879-8712-3456 | 2 | 2 |

[Also please refer to a screenshot example of the hypothetical table]
[image: 1]

Please refer to the image above:

Let's hypothesize that the data contains information such as *'TRANSACTION_NUMBER'* (indicating the unique instances of each transaction), *'UPC_CODE'* (indicating unique product identifiers information), and *'PURCHASED_UNIT'* (indicating how many times that particular product is purchased).

My goal is to generate a column called *"COPURCHASED_FREQUENCY"*. This columnn should contain information about number of times that pairs of UPCs are co-purchased within the same transaction instance indicated by a column 'Transaction Number".

The tricky thing is that we cannot perform this operation on neither R nor Python; instead, this column should be created by SQL operation.

I think what I am trying to create is something similar to co-occurence instance. I cannot think of a particular way to do this as of now, and I would appreciate your help! If you can help with this, that would be great!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It is SQL from Google Big Query!

Answer (score 2):

that would be achievable by using window functions & if you want to show 0 for the ones that have not bought more that once , you can use a case statement :

```
select *
, count(*) over (partition by TRANSACTION_NUMBER,UPC_CODE) as COPURCHASED_FREQUENCY
from youratble
```